# Best code to use for : wp_get_recent_posts exclude?

Tags: wordpress

Many stuff on the web, some are very old (7 years. What is the best code to use, today, for getting the recent Wordpress posts in a sidebar... and to have one category exclude ?

Here are my actual codes, wanting to have all post excluding one cat, then having only one cat recent post under it. Looking for the best ones.

```
<!--- get all latest post for all categories, except for category ID 2  --->
<aside id="recent-posts-4" class="widget widget_recent_entries">
<h3>LATEST NEWS</h3>
<ul>
<?php
$args = array( 'numberposts' => '3', 'exclude' => '2' );
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="Look '.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a> </li> ';
}
?>
</ul>
</aside>

<!--- get 3 latest post for category ID 2 only  --->
<aside id="recent-posts-4" class="widget widget_recent_entries">
<h3>LATEST EVENTS</h3>
<ul>
<?php
$args = array( 'numberposts' => '3', 'cat' => '2' );
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="Look '.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a> </li> ';
}
?>
</ul>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my own answer. Its working (thanks to  [How to Exclude Categories from Sidebar listing of Recent Posts in Wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697151/how-to-exclude-categories-from-sidebar-listing-of-recent-posts-in-wordpress) )

change this

```
'exclude' => '2'
```

to this

```
'cat' => '-2'
```